# Submit data without refreshing page and display the data live in below of form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Someone know how to show the data after submit below the form ?
I have a code like below that function to save the data, but I want after save the data, it will show into below of form. I think like facebook posting wall.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
   $(".submit").click(function() {
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var username = $("#username").val();
        var password = $("#password").val();
        var gender = $("#gender").val();
        var dataString = 'name='+ name + '&username=' + username + '&password=' + password + '&gender=' + gender;

        if(name=='' || username=='' || password=='' || gender=='')
        {
            $('.success').fadeOut(200).hide();
            $('.error').fadeOut(200).show();
        }
        else
        {
           $.ajax({
               type: "POST",
               url: "result.php",
               data: dataString,
               success: function(){
                  $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
                  $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
               }
            });
         }
return false;
});


});
    </script>
```

Comment: just a tip, but knockout.js is great for this kind of stuff :)

so you want to submit data... and instantly integrate with existing data?

Comment: what is the problem? if you have the data, just populate the '.success' element and show it.

Comment: Hi.. so is it possible to add url example : showdata.php into tag .success ?

Comment: do you want to show the datas in existing form or a new form

Answer (score 0):

Just append your response to your specified HTML element( div,span etc ) after success of your ajax requrest.

```
    $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "result.php",
           data: dataString,
           success: function(response){

              $('.success').fadeIn(200).show();
              $('#response').append(response);
              $('.error').fadeOut(200).hide();
           }
        });
```

Response will get appended to your specified HTML element.